# Realm Swift design pattern

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently using the following flow in my app:

- a **UITableViewController**: listing rows
- a **UIViewController**: show details of a clicked row
- **Realm**: persist the data

So the first thing I do is to query `Realm` and populate the `UITableView`.
 When a row is clicked the `UIViewController` is presented to show more details, which are contained in my previously-queried `Realm Object`. Therefore I pass the object in the following way

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UIViewController
        destinationVC.rowData = selectedRowData
        }
```

where `selectedRowData` is the `Realm Object` corresponding to the selected row. 
Now, `UIViewController` allows the user to update some properties, which have to be stored in my `Realm` instance upon a Save action. That being said I **cannot** simply update the `Realm Object` on the go as

```
rowData.myCustomProperty = newCustomPropertyUpdatedByTheUser
```

otherwise `Realm` throws an exception saying I tried to perform a write outside a write statement. Obviously I **do not** want to perform a write at this time, otherwise if the user negates the operation (e.g. by getting back to the `UITableViewController`) I would have the value stored regardless, which is bad. 
I was wondering then what's the best solution/pattern to be used in this case that makes me avoid replication of code as much as possible. 
A solution that came to my mind is to store temporarily the values in some variables/struct and then update `rowData` when the save button is clicked. 
 It works but I personally don't like this solution, e.g. if you update the data model you will have to keep the structure consistent etc, so if you have a better design pattern please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your view controller launches at that point start a transaction with realm.
If you wish to save the changes then commit that transaction, if the user goes back to the without saving then don't commit the transaction.

Comment: Just read the documentation and it's what I was looking for, thanks!